# Can someone explain to me why im getting this error

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Im trying to make a tkinter window but this shows up for some reason, i really dont know what i did wrong

```
root.title('RNG')
root.geometry('300x300')
button = Button(root, text = 'talk', bd = '5',)
button.pack(side = 'top')
text = Text(master=BOTTOM)
text.pack(side=BOTTOM)
```

the error:

```
  File "/home/valtok/PycharmProjects/tests/waifu simulator/RNG.py", line 65, in <module>
    text = Text (master=BOTTOM)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3554, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'text', cnf, kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2561, in __init__
    BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2530, in _setup
    self.tk = master.tk
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

Comment: `master` should be a Tkinter element, not `BOTTOM`

Comment: `text = Text(master=BOTTOM)`: BOTTOM is a tkinter variable, you need to pass in `root`, like `text = Text(master=root)`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
text = Text(master=BOTTOM)
```

Write this:

```
text = Text(master=root)
```